# Security patch 6788 (secrets leak) installation Error on resetforgottenpassword.phtml Hunk #1 FAILED at 28

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am getting this error - 
Hunk #1 FAILED at 28.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml.rej

Please  help  me to resolve this issue .I have already placed .htaccess.sample file in root directory .

Answer (score 1):

Hunk failures are because there is a mismatch between the file contents and what the patch expects.

And that mismatch is occurring on `resetforgottenpassword.phtml`

Have you tried replacing that file with an original copy from the Magento installer archive for your Magento version? Save a copy of your current running version, somebody may have modified your base template instead of creating a custom template and making changes there.

And when you are successful, you will need to apply the changes to `resetforgottenpassword.phtml` in your custom template as well.

Comment: It was actually  my both .htaccess  file was different . so  it was giving error . now it is  resolved.